# How can I get the percentage of missing in a column using agg function?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, aggregate-functions

I'm working with the dataset database_versao_LatLongDecimal_fonteANM_23_01_2019.csv - you can find it here https://www.kaggle.com/edumagalhaes/brazilian-dams-and-brumadinho-households - and I was hoping to find the percentage of missing in the column "CATEGORIA_DE_RISCO", grouped by UF.

This is what I've tried:

```
summary = (
    base_1.groupby(["UF"], sort=False)
    .agg(
        media=("Dano_Potencial__Alta", "count"),
        minimo=("Dano_Potencial__Alta", "mean"),
        Missing_Risco=(
            "CATEGORIA_DE_RISCO",
            lambda x: x.CATEGORIA_DE_RISCO.isnull().sum() / len(x),
        )
    )
    .reset_index()
    .round(1)
)

summary
```

But I keep getting the error:

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'CATEGORIA_DE_RISCO'
```

I understand the error, but I'm not sure why it's happening and how to fix it. I was sure I would find some answer here, but I only found how the get the missing of a column and how to get the percentage of some value. Which is weird, because I used similar logic to the answer of the post [Aggregate groups in Python Pandas and spit out percentage from a certain count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32566866/aggregate-groups-in-python-pandas-and-spit-out-percentage-from-a-certain-count).

Answer (score 2):

Remove column name and instead divide `sum` by length use `mean`:

```
summary = (
    base_1.groupby(["UF"], sort=False)
    .agg(
        media=("Dano_Potencial__Alta", "count"),
        minimo=("Dano_Potencial__Alta", "mean"),
        Missing_Risco=(
            "CATEGORIA_DE_RISCO",
            lambda x: x.isnull().mean(),
        )
    )
    .reset_index()
    .round(1)
)
```

Another idea with helper column:

```
summary = (
    base_1.assign(null_col = base_1['CATEGORIA_DE_RISCO'].isnull())
    .groupby(["UF"], sort=False)
    .agg(
        media=("Dano_Potencial__Alta", "count"),
        minimo=("Dano_Potencial__Alta", "mean"),
        Missing_Risco=("null_col",'mean')
    )
    .reset_index()
    .round(1)
)
```